# Replace a form with a text

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<form>` where the user can input data. When he inputs the right data and the user presses a button, I want to replace this `<form>` with a thank you message. In fact a `<div>` container with text inside should appear.

What are good ways to realise this in Primefaces 3.5 or JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Suppose you have a parent div in which two divs are there. One for form and one for thank you message.
- First, set the form panel as visible and thank you message as invisible.
- If the form is successfully submitted, then change some backing bean value to true which will be responsible for displaying thank you message.
- Now, after form is submitted, change its panel's visibility to `false` and thank you message visibility to `true`.

  ```
     <p:outputPanel id="parentPanel">
       <p:outputPanel id="formPanel" rendered="#{bean.render eq '1'}">
             //Your form here
       </p:outputPanel>
       <p:outputPanel id="textPanel" rendered="#{bean.render eq '2'}">
             //Your thank you message here
       </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
  ```

Here, `render` is an attribute in the bean which will change from `1` to`2` after form is submitted.

Comment: If you are using primefaces, then why don't you use `outputPanel`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, when I use `<p:outputPanel rendered="#{landingPageService.isVisibilityThank()}">` then only the first `div` disappears and nothing is shown on the page...(The value in the rendered attribute is `true`!!!)